# Assign value to an object rjava

Tags: r, object, rjava

I need to assign value to an object using rjava .I need to assign obja (object of classA the value on RHS)

```
  ClassA obja=objb$next()
```

How can this be done?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
obja <- .jnew("fully/qualified/class/name", objb$next())
```

This follows [the documentation for `.jnew`](http://127.0.0.1:16374/library/rJava/html/jnew.html). "fully/qualified/class/name" could be, for example, "java/lang/String".